Why does Sinhala script mark mid vowels in such a strange way?
The vowels E and O are written with a diacritic that goes to the left of the consonant, despite the script being left-to-right, and also O seems to be E+A which doesn't make much sense to me. What caused this state of affairs? Is there a good written source where I can learn more about the history of this script?

Also, why is Ai marked by a second E diacritic while Au is marked by a U diacritic replacing the A component? Why are the long versions of E and O marked by adding a zero diacritic? Thank you

This kind of thing is common in Indic scripts. In Devanagari, short i is to the left of the character (long i to the right); and o, au can appear to be compounds of a+e, a+ai. I believe that in Thai and Lao, the diacritic for e precedes the consonant.
